# Power Bi error get data from SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server

I had received error as below when i want to get data from SQL Server.

[image: error]

Kindly need your help to advise..

Comment: This looks like a permission issue. Have you tried connecting to your database using the same credentials that you are using in the Power BI?

Comment: hi @VKarthik, permission issue from my sql database or from power BI? I already tried but the same error pop up.I already track path above, but missing file Cache.Key.

Comment: PowerBI caches the credentials on the local disk. If the permissions have changed then it would create a problem when you try to access again. What I would suggest is to do test connection again on your data source and see if you are able to connect.

Comment: test connection between SQL server and Power BI? I The error still same. I had check the credential. I used my windows credential.

Comment: anyone know the solutions?